# Trigger google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Does anyone know how to write an appscript that will auto trigger when a user add new value on new row on column A to Column D then the appscript will trigger and type a vlookup(column B&C, sheet2 data, 10, false) on column E and on Column F Vlookup(column B&C, sheet2 data, 20, false) after that it will copy paste as value.

I need to do this because i am running a whatsapp API that have a workflow that will ask user that wants to find out the inventory balance to key in their preferred item, size and phone number then it will populate it on column A to D then will need the information to vlookup our database and then copy paste as value then this will trigger our template workflow to auto send a template message base on the shoe model, size and inventory left if the new row is updated on E and F

I tried to just do a Vlookup at column E and F but when the whatsapp API populate the value on a new row from column A to D with time stamps, shoe model, Serial number, Whatsapp number and it will overwrite the entire row and remove my Vlookup and thus it will not be able to trigger the whatsapp api google sheet to base value on E and F to send out the info back to the user from our google sheet. So the only way around is to write a trigger that automatically types in the vlookup and paste as value so it will trigger the auto message send back. If anyone knows how to write the Appscript which i am very new to would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use an onEdit trigger

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart < 5 && e.value) {
    //put the rest of code in here
  }
}
```